# ¿Cuándo y cómo usar la directiva @content en Sass?

Tags: css, sass, scss

Tengo una duda sobre el funcionamiento de la directiva `@content` en Sass, no me queda claro cómo funciona o cuándo usarla.

Con `@content` se puede llamar a un mixin y añadirle estilos adicionales... pero realmente se puede obtener el mismo resultado sin `@content`. Entonces, ¿para qué usarlo? (aunque seguro dependerá del ejemplo, porque no tendría sentido añadir una directiva "que no sirve").

Por ejemplo:

```
@mixin colores-alarma() {
  color: #660000;
  background-color: #ffdddd;
  border: 2px solid #660000;
  @content;
}

.mensaje-alarma {
  @include colores-alarma() {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
}
```

Es equivalente a:

```
@mixin colores-alarma() {
  color: #660000;
  background-color: #ffdddd;
  border: 2px solid #660000;
}

.mensaje-alarma {
  @include colores-alarma();
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

O al menos, las dos generan lo mismo:

```
.mensaje-alarma {
  color: #660000;
  background-color: #ffdddd;
  border: 2px solid #660000;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

Y mi pregunta, ¿en qué casos es útil usar la directiva `@content`?

Comment: El `use case` más común es cuando el `mixin` genera `reglas` y dentro de estas se incluye el `@content`. Te dejo [este enlace](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/sasss-content-directive) con varios ejemplos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El @content lo he usad en mixin con un enfoque similar al que propones:

Para trabajar mediaqueries donde desee como este ejemplo:

```
@mixin desde($size){
    @if map-has-key($breakpoints,$size){
        // Si el parámetro es el nombre de un tamaño, se extrae desde el map
        @media screen and (min-width: map-get($breakpoints,$size)){
            @content;
        }
    } @else {
        // Si el parámetro no existe en el map, se toma su valor para construir la media query
         @media screen and (min-width: $size){
            @content;
        }
    }
}
```

esto lo he usado así:

```
.elementoCss{
  width: 100%;
  @include desde(768px){
      width: 70%;
      background-color: tomato;
  }
}
```

Otro ejemplo es:

```
$chainable_column : 'chainableEl';

@mixin elActive {
    .#{$chainable_column}.s--active & {
        @content;
    }
}
.#{$chainable_column} {
    &__inner{
         @include elActive {
              transition: transformY(50%);
         }
    }
}
```

Obviamente, como lo dices, su uso puede no ser importante en algunos casos. pero no es que sea inservible la directiva, depende del enfoque.